# Why my Google Form FormResponse doesn't submitted?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I try to submit my Google Form response programmaticaly with Google Apps Script to set unique id to answer (I did it when response heading off to Google Spreadsheet, but it is not useful solution for me because I want to send id in Email Notification generated by add-on while form submitted). I follow to [Google Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#createResponse()):

> Creates a new response to the form. To answer a question item, create an ItemResponse from the item, then attach it to this form response by calling FormResponse.withItemResponse(response). To save the assembled response, call FormResponse.submit(),

and tried to execute this method in onFormSubmit event.

But it failed on FormResponse.submit() with *Exception: Failed to send response. Wait a few minutes and try again. at onFormSubmit*.

```
function onFormSubmit(e){
    var response = '5';

    var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();        
    var questions = form.getItems();
    var textItem=questions[2].asTextItem();
    var itemResponse=textItem.createResponse(response);

    Logger.log(textItem.getTitle()); //Logs right title 'MyTitle'
    Logger.log(itemResponse.getResponse());  //Logs right response '5'

    var formResponse=form.createResponse();
    formResponse.withItemResponse(itemResponse);
    formResponse.submit(); //An exeception occurs here
}
```

What could be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: What do you expect to happen with that last line of code?

Comment: Don't know if that would fix the issue, but you've created an infinite loop. The function is calling itself when you are trying to submit the form. What's the reason for having an `onFormSubmit` trigger? What do you want to accomplish with that? How are you running this function? Manually, from the editor? When a response is submitted? Have you installed this trigger?